# jquery selector for background images

Tags: jquery, image

What is the right selector to pick background image/s of a div?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `css('background-image')`, however, it will return a string like so...

```
url(../images/image.png)
```

To strip away the `url()` wrapper, use this...

```
var image = element.css('background-image').replace(/^url\((.*?)\)$/, '$1');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/7xRdQ/).

Answer (score 0):

Select the divs and get the attribute:

```
$("div").each(function(){
    alert($(this).css("background-image"));
});
```

If you want to skip divs without a background image you can use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to skip those.

Comment: I don't think there's an attribute of background-image, css must be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myElement").css("background-image");
```